# Joining a group in SignalR

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I am developing WPF application where one instance of a program will be able to communicate to other via  SignalR Self-Host. Everything is fine, except that I don't know how and where do I join a group so that program would know to which users send notification. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my sample code:

```
//client side
private async void ConnectAsync()
{
    Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
    Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;
    HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

    //Handle incoming event from server: use Invoke to write to console from SignalR's thread
    HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) =>
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}\r", name, message))
        )
    );
    try
    {
        await Connection.Start();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        StatusText.Content = "Unable to connect to server: Start server before connecting clients.";
        //No connection: Don't enable Send button or show chat UI
        return;
    }

    HubProxy.Invoke<string>("JoinGroup", "foobar").Wait(); // Do I have to do it here?

}
//serverside
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.Group("foobar").AddMessage(name, message);
    }
    public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task AddGroups()
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foobar");
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return AddGroups();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when adding a new Group:

```
public Task AddGroups()
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foobar");
}
```

it for some reason added prefix "hg-MyHub." to the name of the Group so the name of the Group looked like this: "hg-MyHub.foobar" and of course using this code:

```
HubProxy.Invoke<string>("JoinGroup", "foobar").Wait();
```

didn't do anything simply because there was no Group with name "foobar".
Hope this could be usefull for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it almost right, but your `OnConnected` method isn't quite right.

Try changing it to:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foobar");
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

This is basically the code I've used, and the difference is the `base.OnConnected()` part which is my guess as to what's breaking for you.

Comment: Thank you for help, but that was not it. I have posted solution that solved the problem.